# Determine and draw planes and axes of symmetry of a molecule using software (VESTA or Mercury)

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, molecules, software, symmetry

I designed the $\text{MoS}_2$ molecule (bilayer), with polytype 2H in the VESTA. My goal is to draw the plans and axes of symmetry of the bilayer set. According to the information in the literature, this molecule belongs to the $\text{D}_{3d}$ point group. How can I draw and determine the planes and axes of symmetry in VESTA?

These are the parameters I used in VESTA:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Mercury Attempt:

I exported the `.vesta` data to a `.cif` file.

[image]

[image]

Table with space and point groups for $\text{MoS}_{2}$ (taken from `https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-8984/28/35/353002/ampdf`) (see 2H phase for $\text{MoS}_{2}$):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know VESTA well enough to provide an answer for this program.

However because your data are about a crystal structure I suggest to export your model in the `.cif` format.  CCDC's freely available version of CCDC's [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/) is able to read this file type, and add to its visualizations the symmetry elements of the unit cell (Display -> Symmetry Elements).  There will be a new menu where you may choose among the symmetry elements the program is able to recognize, and how they are displayed:

[image]

For example *only* the centres of inversion:

[image]

The export options in Mercury include bitmap `.png`, ray-tracing PovRay `.pov`, and `.vrml` / `.stl`.

---

Given lattice constants and space group $P6_3/mmc$, do not forget to compare your model with the literature known models for example in the freely accessible [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/index.php) about experimental data (entries [#1010993](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1010993.html), [#1011286](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1011286.html), [#1531960](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1531960.html), [#9007660](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9007660.html), [#9009144](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9009144.html)); and consider contributing to its sibling [TCOD](http://www.crystallography.net/tcod/) about theoretical data and [MPOD](http://mpod.cimav.edu.mx/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow your suggestion and do it on Mercury. The objective is to draw the axes and the planes to prove that it is a $\text{D}_{3d}$ structure. To be a $\text{D}_{3d}$ structure, it must have 3 $\text{C}_2$ axes of symmetry. I put what I got on Mercury, in the post. The problem is that I am getting more than 3 axes of type $\text{C}_2$, and I should only get 3 axes of that type. Why do more than 3 axes type $\text{C}_2$ appear to me, when this structure should only have 3 axes type $\text{C}_2$ and what are those 3 axes in the last figure I put in the post?

Comment: In addition, the molecule you took from the COD library must have a bug in Mercury. In $\text{MoS}_2$ with polytype 2H, there is a bilayer and only Mo-S bonds are allowed. In the drawing you have in the images there are Mo-Mo bonds, which should not appear.

Comment: @JoseMarin We are sharing the same page here.  Space group $P6_3/mmc$ (#194) is for _unit cells_ of point group symmetry $D^4_6h$ (IT volume A1, p. 345, the 2006 edition). Yes, the diagram (e.g., http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/194az1.htm) indicates more than 3 $C_2$ axes perpendicular to $2/m$ and $6_3/m$ axes.

Comment: @JoseMarin Mercury is developed by CCDC; contrasting to ICSD with more inclination for organic, and metalorganic compounds. So its geometric approach draws lines between atoms if their distance is quite less than the sum of the van der Waals radii.  With S 1.80 A, Mo 1.90 A, d(Mo-Mo) = 3.15..3.16 A which is lesser than 2 x 1.90 A.  With the input given in your question, I was not able to reproduce the trigonal prisms of your question (vesta 3.4.8); indeed, pressing the «remove duplicate atoms» with default 1e-006 leaves only one Mo and one S (still no prisms).

Comment: @JoseMarin Loading one of the COD entries (#1010993, #1011286, #1531960, #9007660, and #9009144) as `.cif` into Vesta however yielded the prisms of the original question within a blink of an eye; each of them require only one Mo and one S for the model's definition.

Comment: Thank you for your response and explanation regarding the Mercury bug. I still don't understand why there are 24 elements of symmetry and more than 3 $\text{C}_2$ axes, when the material is a bilayer material (even number of layers). I saw an article that said that in these materials the point group depended on the number of layers (even or odd). I put the table in the post.

Comment: In the table it says that the space group is P$6_3$/mmc, but that for N=even (bilayer) the point group is $\text{D}_{3d}$ and in this case it should have only 3 $\text{C}_2$ axes and 12 symmetry operations, which contradicts the Wikipedia table on space groups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups) or the article you suggested to me (which says that this space group belongs to unit cell $\text{D}^4_{6}h$).

Comment: Could you explain to me why there are 24 symmetry operations in this case instead of 12 and why the bilayer belongs to the group $\text{D}^4_{6}h$ instead of $\text{D}_{3d}$, please? What does it mean to belong to the $\text{D}^4_{6}h$ group (I can't find the character table for this point group)? What is the equivalent point group?

Comment: @JoseMarin I think, section 3.1 (p. 11) contains one key: "For example, the 2H-MoS 2 stacking arrangement has space group $D^4_{6h}$ and point group $D_{6h}$ _for its bulk phase_, but the point group is reduced to $D_{3h}$ or $D_{3d}$ for odd or even numbers of layers, respectively."  A symmetry $D_{3h}$ is found e.g., if there is only one layer of these $\ce{MoS2}$ trigonal bipyramides (like a film / 2D) instead of volume / bulk / 3D crystal modeled in $D^4_{6h}$ with maybe hundreds of (alternating) layers, p. 13: "Odd or even numbers of layers of a TMD can lead to different symmetry labels"

Comment: @JoseMarin As lay-out the symmetry operations in $P6_3/mmc$ or $D^4_{6h}$, this were worth a separate question (there already was such a question here, as far as I vaguely remember without pointing to examples of http://faculty.otterbein.edu/djohnston/sym/spacegroups/, though).

Comment: But in this case, I designed a bilayer so the point group is $\text{D}_{3d}$ instead of $\text{D}^{4}_{6h}$. Why does the Mercury software give me the elements of symmetry as if the structure were $\text{D}^{4}_{6h}$ when, in reality, it is bilayer and belongs to $\text{D}_{3d}$?

Comment: Why is the structure not P$\bar{3}$1m ($\text{D}_{3d}$ point group)?